Using a custom modulemap file for pure Swift framework?
When I create an Objective-C framework in Xcode, I can use a custom modulemap file that references other frameworks, e.g.
framework module SomeName {
    requires objc, blocks, objc_arc

    umbrella header "SomeName.h"

    use Security
    export Security
    link framework "Security"

    use Foundation
    export Foundation
    link framework "Foundation"
}

When I now import this framework in Obj-C (@import SomeName;) or in Swift (import SomeName), Security and Foundation are automatically imported as well (use), all their symbols are available (export) and when I have Link Frameworks Automatically (CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK) enabled, it will even automatically link against those two frameworks (link framework).
But how can I do the same for a pure Swift framework?
Xcode automatically generates a modulemap file for my Swift framework
module SomeName.Swift {
  header "SomeName-Swift.h"
  requires objc
}

When I create my own modulemap file instead
module SomeName.Swift {
    header "SomeName-Swift.h"
    requires objc

    use Security
    export Security
    link framework "Security"

    use Foundation
    export Foundation
    link framework "Foundation"
}

and correctly reference it in the build settings, this is what I end up with
module SomeName.Swift {
    header "SomeName-Swift.h"
    requires objc

    use Security
    export Security
    link framework "Security"

    use Foundation
    export Foundation
    link framework "Foundation"
}

module SomeName.Swift {
  header "SomeName-Swift.h"
  requires objc
}

Xcode just keeps appending its auto-generated content and that won't work, as the later definition seems to override the previous one. For an Objective-C framework, Xcode only creates a modulemap file if no modulemap file has been specified in the build settings.
